# How can I create a boolean column based off of a test in R language?

Tags: r, regex, vector

I am trying to create a `betterAtTennis` column that would be calculated based off the `player 1` and `player 2` score. The rows represent 3 games that have been played. Let's just say the first 2 games were won by player 1. The last was lost.

So, I was thinking of using the `isTrue` function like this:

```
tennis-game$betterAtTennis <- isTrue(player1 > player2)
```

But, this only creates a column of `FALSE`. I'm not sure exactly why it doesn't work for all of them or any of them at all. Should I be testing and adding the boolean values in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test and don't use the isTrue

```
tennis-game$betterAtTennis <- tennis-game$player1 > tennis-game$player2

tennis-game$player1 > tennis-game$player2
```

It will return a vector of boolean, which you can add as a new column to your database.

Comment: I actually tried that before doing the complicated, but it didn't work before. And now it does.. must have missed a small detail or something. thank you!

Comment: You'r welcome. If it helped accept the answer. So everyone knows it is answered :-)